# How to use git diff as a difftool?

Tags: git, diff

I want to use it to diff two files which does not belong to any git project. Note that I want to use git diff as a difftool, not set git diff to any difftool.

Comment: `git diff --no-index file1 file2` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+diff+any+files

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the documentation, it should be possible when you pass `--no-index`

> `git diff [<options>] --no-index [--] <path> <path>`
>   compare the given two paths on the filesystem. You can omit the
>   --no-index option when running the command in a working tree controlled by Git and at least one of the paths points outside the
>   working tree, or when running the command outside a working tree
>   controlled by Git.This form is to

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff